# InfoWindow on marker not showed when current location is not found

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an app that implement a MapsView. In the MapsView, there're some markers which one of them I clicked, it will showed me the InfoWindow. It works fine if my current location is found. But the problem is when my current location not found (GPS disable), the marker not showed me the InfoWindow when i click it.

Here's my code

```
//Getting current location
private void getCurrentLocation() {
    mMap.clear();

    //Creating a location object
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Anda harus menyetujuinya agar dapat menggunakan semua fitur yang ada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        }
    }

    if (location != null) {
        //Getting longitude and latitude
        fromLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        fromLatitude = location.getLatitude();

        //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
        origin = new LatLng(fromLatitude, fromLongitude);

        mo=new MarkerOptions().position(origin).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.here));
        my_marker=mMap.addMarker(mo);
        my_marker.setTitle("I'm Here");
        my_marker.setSnippet("Starting point");
        my_marker.setDraggable(true);
    }
}

class GetInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Mohon tunggu");
        dialog.setTitle("Mendapatkan data...");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);

                JSONArray konten = jsono.getJSONArray("konten");
                mMarkersHashMap = new HashMap<Marker, MyMarker>();

                for (int i = 0; i < konten.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String,String> newMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
                    JSONObject object = konten.getJSONObject(i);
                    newMap.put("nama", object.getString("nama"));
                    newMap.put("deskripsi",object.getString("deskripsi"));
                    newMap.put("foto",object.getString("foto"));
                    newMap.put("marker", object.getString("marker"));
                    newMap.put("lat", object.getString("lat"));
                    newMap.put("lng", object.getString("lng"));
                    array.add(newMap);
                }
                return true;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!result) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tidak dapat mengambil data dari server, silahkan cek koneksi internet anda", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    showInfo();
                }
                else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        newMap = array.get(i);
                        mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker(newMap.get("nama"), newMap.get("deskripsi"), newMap.get("foto"), newMap.get("marker"), Double.parseDouble(newMap.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(newMap.get("lng"))));
                    }
                    plotMarkers(mMyMarkersArray);
                }
                }
        });

    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    getCurrentLocation();
}

public void plotMarkers(ArrayList<MyMarker> markers) {
    if(markers.size() > 0) {
        for (MyMarker myMarker : markers)
        {
            dest = new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude());
            markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(dest);
            location_marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
            Target target = new PicassoMarker(location_marker);
            targets.add(target);

            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.marker);
            int width = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
            int height = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

            Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this).load(myMarker.getmIcon()).resize(width, height).onlyScaleDown().into(target);
            mMarkersHashMap.put(location_marker, myMarker);

            i = getIntent();
            if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {
                location_marker.setTitle(i.getStringExtra("nama"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dest, 16));
            }
            else {
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter
{
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        View v  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_windowlayout, null);

        MyMarker myMarker = mMarkersHashMap.get(marker);

        TextView markerLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_label);
        markerLabel.setText(myMarker.getmLabel());

        ImageView foto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.foto);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(myMarker.getmImage()).placeholder(R.layout.progress).error(R.mipmap.error).into(foto);

        TextView anotherLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.another_label);
        anotherLabel.setText("Baca selengkapnya...");

        if (myMarker.getmImage() != null) {
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(myMarker.getmImage())
                    .placeholder(R.layout.progress)
                    .into(foto, new MarkerCallback(marker));
        }

        return v;
    }
}

public class MarkerCallback implements Callback {
    Marker marker=null;

    MarkerCallback(Marker marker) {
        this.marker=marker;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Tidak dapat mengambil gambar!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Any answer will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: where do you call plotMarkers function?

Comment: Please check my edited post. I call `plotMarkers` in `onPostExecute` in `GetInfo` class.

Comment: call 
     mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
in your 
     onMapReady
Callback.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by adding this code `marker.showInfoWindow();` in `onMarkerClick`